# MapBox Maps iOS SDK: Is there a way to animate PointAnnotation when it's being selected

Tags: ios, swift, mapbox, mapbox-ios

I migrated from old **Mapbox Maps SDKs for iOS and macOS v6.x.x** to **mapbox-maps-ios v10.1.0**.
A lot of API got changed.

I was able to restore same functionality using new SDK, however I could not find a way to animate annotations upon selection.

Before I used `MGLAnnotationView`, or `MGLAnnotationImage` for displaying annotations, and I could easily animate `MGLAnnotationView` by applying animation block with transformations I needed.

In a new SDK it's not the same. Annotations are now represented by `struct PointAnnotation`, therefore animation API is not accessible, as it's not a `UIView` subclass anymore.

What I'm looking for is a simple scale animation that should happen when user tap on the annotation.

Animation scales pin for 1.1 factor and return to 1.0, with duration of 350ms. It is not repeating animation, suppose to happen only once when user tap on the annotation.

I checked an example projects and from what I understand animation is possible by manipulating layers, but I'm not sure how to do that exactly.

Looking for help

Comment: You're going to have to take a crack at layer annotations to get this to work.

Answer (score 0):

As of Mapbox v10.4.3, the solution that works for me is by using View Annotations. You can add custom gesture recognizers, animations, etc inside your custom annotation view. https://docs.mapbox.com/ios/maps/guides/annotations/view-annotations/#create-a-view-annotation

```
let sampleCoordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 39.7128, longitude: -75.0060)
let options = ViewAnnotationOptions(geometry: Point(sampleCoordinate), allowOverlap: true, anchor: .center)
      let annotationView = CustomAnnotationView()
      annotationView.rx.tapGesture().when(.recognized).subscribe(onNext: { [weak self] _ in
        guard let self = self else { return }
        self.viewModel.input.tappedAnnotation()
        /// You can animate annotation view resize here when tapping specific annotation view, or you can also add it inside the custom annotation view
      }).disposed(by: self.disposeBag)
      try? self.mapView.viewAnnotations.add(annotationView, options: options)

class CustomAnnotationView: UIView {
    // Do your customizations here
}
```